# In converting the Struts forms to PDF, XmlWorkerHelper is not the closing the <html:text> input tags

Tags: pdf, itext, struts-1, xmlworker

```
<td>
    <html:text name="LIHF" property="documentNumber" styleId="documentNumber" disabled="true" styleClass="textarea168" />
</td>
```

.

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new StringReader(newHTML));
```

Error

```
com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag td found, expected closing tag input.
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:134)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:395)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:70)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:235)
```

I am using:

- itextpdf - 5.5.4 jar
- xmlworker - 5.4.0 jar
- struts form 1.3.8 jar

I passed the string -

```
String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
```

pdf is generated.

As soon as I pass the struts form element it is generating the error of input tags not closed.

Comment: m using the itextpdf - 5.5.4 jar and xmlworker - 5.4.0 jar

Comment: struts form 1.3.8 jar

Comment: i passed the string - String k = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>"; pdf is generated.

Comment: as soon as i passes the the struts form element it is generating the error of input tags not closed.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 mistakes:

1. Mixing incompatible versions of iText and XMLWorker.
2. Not using Maven but using jars directly.
3. `<html:text ... />` is a Struts tag, not a HTML tag. XMLWorker can only parse rendered HTML to PDF. Struts needs to parse it first before you give it to XMLWorker. This is why `<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>` will work, but `<html:text ... />`, or any other Struts tag, won't work.

To fix 1 and 2, turn your project into a Maven project and add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To fix 3, Struts needs to generate the complete HTML first. I don't know anything about Struts so I cannae tell ya how to do that.

Comment: thanks Amedee for ur comments, i can go with the 1st point, i will find the compatible version of itext and xmlworker.

Comment: As m not authorized to use the Maven, in our working project. We still use the jars directly.

Comment: through javascript when m fetching the inner html, at that time parsing takes place. and at that time while parsing input tags are not getting closed.

Comment: `XMLWorker` only accepts parsed HTML. If your Javascript parsing doesn't correctly close the tags and/or turns the Struts tags into valid HTML tags, then there is nothing you can do. Validate your parsed HTML with the W3 Validator to confirm.